# GL_INVALID_OPERATION error 1218 (0x0502) when using simple OpenGL commands glvertex2i, glColor3ub

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

This is my first time using OpenGL, so this may be a stupid question, but my code is pulling a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error (`1218` or `0x0502`) between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. I'm only calling a couple simple commands but `glGetError()` returns `0` at the start of this function, and `1218` at the end.

This function is intended to be used to draw a single instance of any simple shape, and after stepping through in the debugger, the variables are what I intended them to be. Also note that, despite this being a stupid question, I spent several hours last night and several hours today searching Google and my textbook for possible solutions, and have found nothing helpful due to the vague nature of OpenGL errors.

```
void drawShape(GLenum type, int numPoints, GLubyte r, GLubyte g, GLubyte b, vertex vertices, ...) {
    glBegin(type);
    glColor3ub(r, g, b);

    // iterate through vertices
    va_list vertexList;
    va_start(vertexList, vertices); // use vertexList for iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
        vertex point = i == 0 ? vertices : va_arg(vertexList, vertex);
        // add a new point at (x, y)
        glVertex2i(std::get<0>(point), std::get<1>(point));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

This function is called as follows:

```
drawShape(GL_LINE, 2, 0, 0, 0, vertex{ 10, 10 }, vertex{ 400, 10 });
```

And the context I'm using is FreeGLUT which is initialized as follows:

```
// gross workaround for calling init with no arguments
int argc = 1;
char *argv[1] = { (char*)"" };
glutInitContextVersion(4, 1);
glutInit(&argc, argv);
// RGB window, double buffer
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
// sets values necessary for window initialization
glutInitWindowPosition(INIT_X, INIT_Y);
glutInitWindowSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

// draw the window and create the scene
glutCreateWindow(WORKING_WINDOW_TITLE);
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1); // set clear color to white
glutDisplayFunc(render);
glutMainLoop();
```

Comment: Please show a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Do you even have a valid context? With which parameters do you call the function?

Comment: Are you using a core context? Secondly is your OpenGL context "current" context when your function gets called?

Comment: @BDL I'm calling the function as follows:

`drawShape(GL_LINE, 2, 
  0, 0, 0, 
  vertex{ 10, 10 }, 
  vertex{ 400, 10 });
`

Comment: @Robinson added more detail above

Comment: Make sure you want to be using this ancient OpenGL api.  It's a dead end.  You should be learning how to write shaders.  The best tutorial is at http://open.gl and starts right on the front page.   What you are doing is like learning how to program for Windows 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the call to `glBegin` itself. `GL_LINE` is not a valid parameter for this function. Due to this, all commands after that are not called inside a valid `glBegin/glEnd` block.

If you want to draw lines, the correct parameter is `GL_LINES`.

The first step when debugging an OpenGL application that doesn't support a debug context should always be to identify which function call produces the first error. This can, for example, be done by calling `glGetError()` after each OpenGL call until the problematic line is found. Also note, that `glError` returns errors in arbitrary order if more than one error happened.

Comment: So I should simply change the first parameter of the function call to `GL_LINES`? I tried that and got the same error.

Comment: I also get the same problem when calling `drawShape(GL_POLYGON, 4,
  0, 50, 200,
  vertex{ 10, 200 },
  vertex{ 110, 200 },
  vertex{ 10, 400 },
  vertex{ 110, 400 });`

Comment: You should start by changing this parameter and then identify which line exactly causes the error.